# PHP trying to store numbers in for loop into array

Tags: php, arrays, math, numbers

Let's say I have this code:

```
<?php

$aLevel[] = 98;

function experience($L) {
 $a=0;
  for($x=1; $x<$L; $x++) {
    $a += floor($x+300*pow(2, ($x/7)));
    $aLevel[$x-1] = $a; // we minus one to comply with array
  }
 return floor($a/4);
}

for($L=1;$L<100;$L++) {
 echo 'Level '.$L.': '. number_format(experience($L)). '<br />';
}

echo $aLevel[0]; // Level 1 should output 0 exp
echo "<br />" . $aLevel[1]; // Level 2 should output 83 exp
// et cetera
?>
```

I am trying to make an array to store the exp. So level 1 would be `$aLevel[0]` and the EXP would be 0 (obviously) and level 2 would be `$aLevel[1]` and EXP would be 83 and so on.

The code below... it works. The experience and level loop works but the array doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between the numbers in the array and the numbers returned by `experience`? It looks like you're doing a lot of calculations multiple times by looping through 1-n for every n, but maybe it's because I don't see what you're going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from your scoping issue (the `$aLevel` used inside the function is not the same as outside), you are calculating the experience WAY too many times. When $L = 98, you calculate experience for levels 1-97 and then when $L = 99 you do them all over again. Also, you're dividing your return value by 4 but not the values you're storing in the array.

Assuming I understand the algorithm you're going for, this is how I might do it:

```
function getExperienceByLevel ($maxLevel)
{
  $levels = array ();
  $current = 0;
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxLevel; $i++){
    $levels[$i - 1] = floor ($current / 4);
    $current +=  floor($i+300*pow(2, ($i/7)));
  }
  return $levels;
}


$aLevels = getExperienceByLevel (100);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
  echo 'Level ' . ($i + 1) . ': '. number_format($aLevels[$i]) . "<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is set in a function, so it is not available in the global scope.

this works (better not to use `global`, but in this case it is a quick and dirty solution):
[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/715eff8c165479bf4766c4307c5eff83d9fda37d)

```
<?php 

$aLevel[] = 98;

function experience($L) {
global $aLevel;
 $a=0;
  for($x=1; $x<$L; $x++) {
    $a += floor($x+300*pow(2, ($x/7)));
    $aLevel[$x-1] = $a; // we minus one to comply with array
  }
 return floor($a/4);
}

for($L=1;$L<100;$L++) {
 echo 'Level '.$L.': '. number_format(experience($L)). '<br />';
}

echo $aLevel[0]; // Level 1 should output 0 exp
echo "<br />" . $aLevel[1]; // Level 2 should output 83 exp
// et cetera
?>
```

Comment: The last two echos return `98` and `332`... which is .. weirdly not right. :S

Comment: I got: 332<br />699. While testing I removed `$x-1`

Comment: Are John's results (332 and 699) are 4x the correct numbers (83 and 174)? Maybe because you're not dividing those `$a` values by 4 before you add them to the array.

Answer (score 0):

The $aLevel[] array is not accessible outside the function (see variable scope).  At the end of your script, $aLevel only contains the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 98 ) 98
```

...which is correct as the $aLevel array inside the function is not the same variable.

Try returning $aLevel from your function back to your main script and it will work.